# How to set icon on PrismContentPage Navigation Bar?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Please give solution fast

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:commonViews="clrnamespace:Lawyer_Diaries.Views.CommonViews;assembly=Lawyer_Diaries"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Lawyer_Diaries.Views.DashBoard"          
             Padding="{StaticResource Paddingios}">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve]. BTW Stack Overflow is now coding service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Icon to the properties of Content Page just like padding..
e.g.
Icon="someImage.png";